# What is wrong with this PostgreSQL statement?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following statement that I need to run on a table which has a geometry column. I am getting a WKT from Oracle using my C# program and then attempting to insert it into PostgreSQL using an npgsql connection.

```
highways=# INSERT INTO cluster_125m (CELL_GEOM) 
VALUES(ST_GeomFromWKT('POLYGON ((80000.0 17280.0, 80125.0 17280.0, 80125.0 17405.0, 80000.0 17405.0, 80000.0 17280.0))'));
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  function st_geomfromwkt(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO cluster_125m (CELL_GEOM) VALUES(ST_GeomFromWKT('...
                                                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to
add explicit type casts.
```

What is the issue here and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use function `ST_GeomFromText` instead of `ST_GeomFromWKT`.